# Why is the time complexity of checking parity of integer $O(1)$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

[image]

Can someone please explain why "checking a bit" is $O(1)$?

In our class, we were only told the number of binary operations for multiplications and additions between two integers
so I don't know what "checking a bit" falls under
and how many EBOs/elementary bit operations it consists of.

Comment: This whole question might be better suited to a more computer science oriented stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that in computers integers are stored as binary bit strings.  Reviewing [binary representation](https:///https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Counting_in_binary) of integers might be helpful.
If the integer is even the last bit is 0.  If the integer is odd, the last bit is 1.  So to determine if an integer is even or odd we only need examine if the last bit of the binary representation is zero or one.  This can be done in a single if/ then statement.  Hence the time to determine the evenness or oddness of an integer is O(1).

Comment: This was introduced in an introductory number theory course, so I am not famiilar with time complexity in the context of computer science (yet). Is a single if/then loop $O(1)$ complexity always? Why? Suppose that 2 bits needed to be checked. What then? 2 if/then statements? But wouldn't the upper bound still be just some arbitrarily large constant? So any number of if/then statements is also $O(1)$? That seems not very intuitive.

Comment: Do "else" branches add any complexity (because there are two cases, odd or even)

Comment: Again, for any single binary integer, we only need to check the *last* bit.  Checking a single bit for 0 or 1 is O(1).  Evaluating this "if/ then" takes place only one time and before any loop.  In this exercise, for any single calculation of A(n) = B(n), we need only  decide once.


If a different exercise, had a similar if/ then *inside* a loop from 1 to k, evaluating all the "if/then" 's would be O(k).


If we had two consecutive "if/ then" 's, this would be O(2).

Comment: Students have been trained to think extremely detailed, exact and to cover every detail.  However, for Big O, O(...), we can throw that all away and only consider- what is an upper bound?  What is the maximum possible result?

Ex. for sufficiently large n, $c n^2 < n^3$.  For many courses and/or professors the choice of c has no effect.  Inequalities can hide a lot of details and enable us to throw away other terms.  Big O, assumes, or at least most of the professors I've seen, assume "for sufficiently large n".

Time complexity without Big O, includes all those nitty gritty details again.